# How to make cookies separate in different windows in nw.js?

Tags: javascript, cookies, nw.js

I use nw.js to display a web page in an `<iframe>`. However when I use `gui.Window.open` to open a new window, all the windows share the same cookies. I need to login the web page using different accounts but I cannot make the cookies separate in different windows. How can I manage the cookies in that way? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that if you add `"single-instance": false` into the `package.json` file, the app will be able to run multiple instances and each of the instances has its own, separate cookies.